# Cannot call/write file in nifi docker: Permission denied issue

Tags: docker, apache-nifi, permission-denied

Run Nifi docker version 1.9.0 or later

[image]

then mount with folder /home/volume

[image]

cannot read data from (because nifi's docker run by nifi user not by root user)
ExecuteStreamCommand[id=2965940d-6419-35fc-db50-ae1368370a77] Could not create external process to run command: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/volume/test.py": error=13, Permission denied

[image]

Any suggestions?

I tested with **chmod 775 /home/volume** and also **chmod 775 /home/volume/test.py**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wi1kA.png)

Answer (score 0):

have you try chmod the directory **/home/volume/test.py**

```sh
chmod 755 /home/volume/
```

Comment: Thanks Arief, I did, but cannot allow this command, see additional information